# android global variable, getApplicationContext with ClassCastException

Tags: android, variables, global, classcastexception

Follow the advice from Stack Overflow question and answer, I create a class (Constant), and try to declare and use it as the global variable, but it failed to cast, can not find any good answer for this issue, I tried to define either "Constant" or ".Constant" in Manifest file, none of the definition works.

Please help me out.

```
Constant con = ((Constant)getApplicationContext());  // failed to cast here
con.setClientid(Integer.parseInt(clientid));

import android.app.Application;

public class Constant extends Application {
    private int gClientid;
    public int getClientid() { return gClientid; }   
    public void setClientid(int cid) { gClientid = cid; }   
}
```

Manifest

```
<application android:name=".Constant" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

Comment: you are trying to cast getApplicationContext which is of type Context into your Constant class, which is of type Application. It cannot cast from one to another.

Answer (score 1):

```
Constant con = (Constant)getApplication();  // failed to cast here
con.setClientid(Integer.parseInt(clientid));

import android.app.Application;

public class Constant extends Application {
    private int gClientid;
    public int getClientid() { return gClientid; }   
    public void setClientid(int cid) { gClientid = cid; }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct synthax should be Constant con = (Constant) this.getApplication(); inside your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Replace getApplicationContext() with getApplication() and you should be able to cast a class extending application.

Comment: I tried different combination, getApplicationContext or getApplication(), remove the (), change the name from ".Constant" to "Constant", but still the same problem.

Comment: its definitely getApplication(). about the manifest declaration. try to declare it through the manifest interface. probably you don't have it declared properly. apart from using the getApplication() method your code is ok. the only thing left is declaring it properly into the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering to a old post,
but just for the people still getting similar problem.

I think his problem is the part of

```
<application android:name=".Constant" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

My problem is solved by including whole specific path to the class instead of ".Constant".
ex. "com.example.Constant"